# Using Selenium with Python on an existing Java project

Tags: python, java, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to use Selenium, written in Python for testing an existing Java project?
The languages need to be equal or is it possible to write on Selenium in another language

Answer (score 0):

Selenium will open a web browser and interact to your project through it.
It did not have access to your code, it will simulate a human accessing to your website.

To test your project, you will launch it and launch selenium in parallel.

To answer your question, the language don't need to be the same as the one of your project as it will be an independent script.